# Conversion bytea[] of PostgreSQL to oracle 12c

Tags: postgresql, oracle12c

I am new to PostgreSQL and migrating PostgreSQL metadata to oracle..

Following table contains bytea[] data type in second column.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_spl_contest_type
(
  contest_type_id bigint NOT NULL,
  contest_cfg bytea[] NOT NULL,
)
```

Please help us to convert the above table from PostreSQL to Oracle 12.

Comment: bytea[] in postgresql is an array of bytea elements.

sqlines converted the table from postgresql to oracle as below.

CREATE TABLE tbl_spl_contest_type
(
  contest_type_id number(19) NOT NULL,
  contest_cfg blob[] NOT NULL
)      

While executing the above table in oracle database, we got the following exception 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Oracle does not support arrays.You need to split this up into a regular 1:many relationship with a `BLOB` column.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: What a *bizarre* way to model something. An array of `bytea`? Weird.